# React. Attempted import error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, импорт, export

всё делаю как обычно, файл tourReducer.js

```
import {GET_TOURS} from "../actions/tourAction";

const InitialTour = {
    tours: [],
};

export const tourReducer = (tour = InitialTour, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_TOURS :
            return {...tour, tours: action.payload}
        default :
            return tour;
    }
}
```

делаю импорт из rootReducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { userReducer } from './userReducer';
import { modalReducer } from './modalReducer';
import {loadingReducer} from "./loadingReducer";
import {playerReducer} from "./playerReducer";
import {teamsReducer} from "./teamsReduser";
import {leagueReducer} from "./leagueReducer";
import {matchReducer} from "./matchReducer";
import {videoReducer} from "./videoReducer";
import {tourReducer} from "./tourReducer";

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  modal: modalReducer,
  loading: loadingReducer,
  player: playerReducer,
  team: teamsReducer,
  league: leagueReducer,
  match: matchReducer,
  video: videoReducer,
  tour: tourReducer,
});
```

и в конечном итоге получаю:

```
./src/store/reducers/rootReducer.js
Attempted import error: 'tourReducer' is not exported from './tourReducer'.
```

хотя если сравнивать код tourReducer.js с другими редюсерами то все импорты я делаю аналогично и малейшего представления не имею в чём ошибка?